# Update Shopware from 4.1.1 to 5.2.6

Tags: upgrade, shopware

I have shopware 4.1.1 that i want to upgrade it to 5.2.6

Please let me know , how can I upgrade it

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you haven't tried to find a solution (show your work!)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little to late but look here:

http://community.shopware.com/Downloads_cat_448.html#updates

There you can get the Update packages.

In your case, you have to do several updates:

1. 4.1.1 => 4.2.0
2. 4.2.0 => 5.0.0
3. 5.0.0 => 5.2.8 (current version)